# Template class declaring pointer to its unspecialized self

Tags: c++, templates

I was surprised to find out that the following code compiles:

```
template<typename T>
struct Test {
    Test* ptr; // I don't need to specify the template arguments?
    // Test<T>* ptr;  I was expecting to declare it like this
};

int main() {
    Test<int> t;
    Test<int> tt;
    t.ptr = &tt;

    return 0;
}
```

Why is the member declaration without specifying template arguments allowed in this context? Compiled using Visual Studio 2008 if it matters.

Comment: Because the standard says so. vOv

Comment: Nice find, @Logic.

Comment: if you like you can still write `Test<T>`, but why would you? You only need it in case you want a `Test<S>` or the like

Comment: Thanks for the duplicate link. That answers my question pretty clearly.